# Max record in sql aginst ID

Tags: sql-server, max

I have this query

```
SELECT 
    MAX([ID]),
    [sr].[EmpId],
    [vw].[EmpName],
    [sr].[IAmount]
FROM 
    [SRev] [sr]
INNER JOIN 
    [vwemp] [vw] ON [sr].[EmpId] = [vw].[EmpId]
INNER JOIN 
    [SalaryType] [st] ON [st].[SalaryType] = [sr].[SalaryType]
WHERE 
    [sr].[EmpId] IN (125553)
GROUP BY 
    [sr].[EmpId], [vw].[EmpName], [sr].[IAmount];
```

This query returns a result set like this:

```
(No column name)    EmpId   EmpName     IAmount
-----------------------------------------------
1687106             12553   BABC         -8500
2136112             12553   BABC           936
1782854             12553   BABC          1225
1687106             12553   BABC          3000
2628907             12553   BABC         22839
```

I only want max against record against each empid

```
(No column name)    EmpId    EmpName    IAmount
-----------------------------------------------
2628907             12553    BABC        22839
```

Comment: Since you're gouping by `IAmount` and there are obviously different values in this column you will get a result row for each `IAmount` value. Question is: Which value do you want to get for `IAmount`?

Comment: I think what you are afer here is to take out `IAmount` from your select and grouping columns, otherwise as Onkel Toob pointed out, you'll get a result for every individual value, as you are grouping by this too. Whack it all in a backet and give it an alias, and then join it back onto your original table on the ID to get your value.

Comment: sorry typo: backet = bracket!

Comment: yes when i eliminate IAmount then this shows correct record but  i have to add IAmount .. so how i do this

Comment: You have an attempted answer below, @seesharp . Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to use `ROW_NUMBER` and a CTE:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT ID, --not sure of the lias for this one
           sr.EmpID,
           vw.EmpName,
           sr.IAmount,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sr.EmpId ORDER BY ID DESC) AS RN
    FROM SRev sr
         INNER JOIN vwemp vw ON sr.EmpId = vw.EmpId
         INNER JOIN SalaryType st ON st.SalaryType = sr.SalaryType
     WHERE sr.EmpId = 125553)
SELECT ID,
       EmpId,
       EmpName,
       IAmount
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Note this is untested, as I don't have any consumable sample data or DDL (the result set above it from your query).